# Get Batch file to run relative to actual folder, not shortcut

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've created a few batch files that moves files around relative to the folder the batch file is in.

I've added the folder to my Taskbar using Toolbars => New Toolbar..., however now when I run the batch files, the starting position is My Documents (U:), not the actual location of the batch files.  Is there any way I can get it to use the actual path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the following at the top of your batch file:

```
CD /D %~dp0
```

Explanation:

- The `/D` option tells `CD` to change current drive as well as current directory for a drive.
- `%0` is the name of the batch file
- The `~` says [we want to use some modifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)
- `d` expands to drive letter.
- `p` expands to a path.

So `%~dp0` is the directory in which the batch file resides.

Comment: The CD works perfectly, but it doesn't change the drive designation, so the script still tries to run on U:\

Comment: Have added %~d0 to change drive following your explanation.

Comment: @ck - Forgot about drives, sorry.  It's probably easiest to use `CD /D`.  Have edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: we can use `PUSHD` instead of `CD /D`